# Differentiability of $fg$ when one differentiable and other not but product differentiable.

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

I conjectured the following theorem :

Let $I$ be an open interval and let  $a\in I.\,\,$  If $f,g:I\to\mathbb{R}$  such that $f$ is differentiable at $x=a$ with $f(a)=f'(a)=0$ and $g(x)$ is a bounded function over $(a-h,a+h)$ for some $h>0$ , then $f(x)g(x)$ is differentiable at $x=a.$

Proof: Let $\phi(x)=f(x)g(x)$ and let $\exists\,\, M>0\text{  such that }|g(x)|<M\,\,\forall \,\,x\in(a-h,a+h)$

$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\phi(a+h)-\phi(a)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)g(a+h)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}g(a+h)$

Now $-M\left |\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}\right | \le \left |\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}g(a+h)\right |\le M\left |\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}\right |$

$\implies 0\le \lim_{h\to0}\left |\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}g(a+h)\right |\le 0$
$\implies \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\phi(a+h)-\phi(a)}{h}=0$

$\implies \phi(x)$ is differentiable.

Is this working correct. Can we further generalised it ? any similar results most welcome?

Comment: It seems correct to me.

Comment: If you assume more on $f$, you can even allow $g$ to be unbounded in a way that the goodness of $f$ compensates the badness of $g$.